# How can I plot a layered graph on a three-dimensional plane

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, graphs-and-networks

Given a `LayeredGraph`:

```
LayeredGraphPlot[{1 -> 3, 3 -> 1, 1 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 1 -> 6, 2 -> 4, 
    2 -> 6, 3 -> 4, 3 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 6, 5 -> 6}, 
    VertexLabeling -> True];
```

[image]

I like to present it on a three-layer surface:

[image]

Such that vertices {3,1,2} be placed on the top layer; {5,4} on the middle layer; and {6} on the bottom layer. Directed arrows from the top layer towards bottom should be `Blue` and from the bottom towards the top be `Gray`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
edges = {1 -> 5, 1 -> 6, 1 -> 3, 5 -> 2, 5 -> 4, 6 -> 7, 2 -> 6, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 7 -> 4};

vertices = {4, 3, 7, 1, 2, 6, 5};

layers = {1, 2, 4};

vcoords = Thread[vertices -> 
    Join @@ MapThread[Join[##, 2] &, 
     {MapIndexed[CirclePoints[#2[[1]]/4, #] &, layers] /. {{a_?NumericQ, _}} :> {{0, 0}}, 
      MapIndexed[ConstantArray[#2 - 1, #] &, layers]}]];

Graph3D[edges, 
  VertexCoordinates -> vcoords, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[.4], EdgeForm[Thin], Lighting -> "Neutral", 
   LightBlue, InfinitePlane[{0, 0, #}, {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}] & /@ 
    Range[0, 2]}, Boxed -> False], 
 Graph3D[edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  ImageSize -> Medium], 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.2]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `FaceGrids` to indicate the planes:

```
facegrids = {#, {{}, {0, 1, 2}}} & /@ Join[#, -#] & @ Most[IdentityMatrix[3]];

Graph3D[edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 ImageSize -> Medium, 
 FaceGrids -> facegrids, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.2]]
```

[image]

**Update:** Styling edges:

```
Graph3D[edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 VertexSize -> Medium, BaseStyle -> Arrowheads[Large], 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> (Arrow @ Tube[#, .03] &), 
 EdgeStyle -> MapIndexed[# -> ColorData[97][#2[[1]]] &, edges], 
 ImageSize -> Medium, FaceGrids -> facegrids, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.2]]
```

[image]

```
Graph3D[edges, VertexCoordinates -> vcoords, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], ImageSize -> Medium, 
 FaceGrids -> facegrids, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.2], 
 VertexSize -> Medium, EdgeStyle -> Black, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Arrowheads[Large, Appearance -> "Projected"], Thick, 
   Arrow[BezierCurve[{#[[1]], {#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]], #[[-1, 3]]}, #[[-1]]}], .1]}&), 
 Properties -> {(5 \[DirectedEdge] _) -> {EdgeStyle -> Directive[Dashed, Red]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: The structure of the layered graph is fine, but I wanted to show each layer on a separate plane (surface) so that the web of links between the layers is apparent. Also, how do you set the colors of linkages between the layers?

Comment: Yes, this is what I had in mind. Perfect!!!

Comment: Is there a way to choose edge colors? In the current graphs, edges are difficult to differentiate, and the arrows and edges are blurry somehow, maybe due to my computer.

Comment: @Tugrul, please see the update.

Comment: I just wonder: Is it a legitimate question if I ask the MMA Stack Exchange Forum to help me in developing a new `LayeredGraph3D[...]` function to perform your above answer in a more systematic manner? Sorry if I asked you an improper question. Thanks.

Comment: @Tugrul, that would be a good question.

Comment: The very last 3D graph looks very nice: clear and esthetic with red dashed arrows. Thank you for this addition.